# AEROSPIKE_ERR_CONNECTION Socket write error: 32, 127.0.0.1:3000 on ubuntu wsl

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, aerospike

1. I am trying to install aerospike on ubuntu wsl.

Installed aerospike tools, aerospike server community. What other requirements could be there to use the aerospike?

I am getting **aerospike connection ERROR**.

```
*ubuntu@MANU:/$* ls

aerospike-server-community-5.7.0.8-ubuntu20.04  bin   dev  home  lib    lib64   media  opt   root  sbin  srv  tmp  var
aerospike.tgz                                   boot  etc  init  lib32  libx32  mnt    proc  run   snap  sys  usr

*ubuntu@MANU:/$* cd aerospike-server-community-5.7.0.8-ubuntu20.04

*ubuntu@MANU:/aerospike-server-community-5.7.0.8-ubuntu20.04$* aql

Seed:         127.0.0.1

User:         None

Config File:  /etc/aerospike/astools.conf /home/ubuntu/.aerospike/astools.conf

2021-11-20 13:10:36 WARN Failed to connect to seed 127.0.0.1 3000. AEROSPIKE_ERR_CONNECTION Socket write error: 32, 127.0.0.1:3000
Error -10: Failed to connect
```

2. I get this ERROR when trying to start Aerospike:

```
*ubuntu@NUPUR:/aerospike-server-community-5.7.0.8-ubuntu20.04$* systemctl start aerospike

System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

**Edit:**

I found why systemctl could not be working here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646338/problem-creating-a-service-on-kali

but **service** is not working either.

```
ubuntu@NUPUR:/aerospike-server-community-5.7.0.8-ubuntu20.04$* sudo service aerospike start

[sudo] password for ubuntu:

aerospike: unrecognized service
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you install and start the server. Check the [Ubuntu install documentation](https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/linux/ubuntu/index.html) for step by step instructions. If you have started the server and still get errors, check the server log files for details on what would have prevented the server from properly starting up.

Comment: I added to my question, the error I am getting when trying to start aerospike.

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions on the link provided? (Just checking to make sure... did the install script complete successfully?)

Comment: The Ubuntu instructions will not work for Ubuntu on WSL because https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/994. I believe the Linux package will since I don't believe it relies on a specific init system: https://download.aerospike.com/docs/operations/install/linux/other.

Comment: BTW, I've found there are just too many workarounds to justify using WSL in its current state - I eventually switched to using Ubuntu on HyperV. The lack of init system was a huge hindrance, unable to communicate with docker containers from WSL was eventually a deal-breaker.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize this at all. Thanks @kporter.

Comment: @Meher, it was installed successfully with $ sudo ./asinstall  . After that I get this:                                       
/$ sudo service aerospike start                             aerospike: unrecognized service

Comment: It would then seem the installation was not successful. Seems @kporter provided some details about why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks @kporter. ubuntu on vm worked.