# Aerospike Connect to kafka: docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /etc/aerospike-kafka-outbound/aerospike-kafka-outbound.yml

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aerospike

I am trying Aerospike Connect to Kafka.
OS: Windows

I referred https://enterprise.aerospike.com/docs/connect/streaming-from-asdb/installing/from-asdb-to-kafka-installing.html.
I referred: '# With Aerospike 5.0 and later'  for deploying on docker

I have these running in docker:

My Windows path for the file: C:/aerospike-kafka-outbound/aerospike-kafka-outbound.yml

```
C:\Users\Nupur>docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                              NAMES
1114b8a97406   aerospike/aerospike-kafka-outbound:4.0.0   "/bin/sh -c '/opt/${…"   37 seconds ago   Up 29 seconds                                      compassionate_hofstadter
93343be1d481   aerospike/aerospike-tools                  "wrapper aql -h 172.…"   4 hours ago      Up 4 hours                                         dreamy_mendeleev
5f00ee532c4e   aerospike/amc                              "/opt/amc/amc ' -con…"   8 days ago       Up 4 hours      0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp             aerospike-consoles
a81ff04dbd74   aerospike/aerospike-server-enterprise      "/usr/bin/tini -r SI…"   8 days ago       Up 4 hours      0.0.0.0:3000-3002->3000-3002/tcp   aerospike
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\Nupur>docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /C:/aerospike-kafka-outbound/aerospike-kafka-outbound.yml:/etc/aerospike-kafka-outbound/aerospike-kafka-outbound.yml aerospike/aerospike-kafka-outbound:4.0.0
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /etc/aerospike-kafka-outbound/aerospike-kafka-outbound.yml.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

As for the front slash used in Windows path, on using backslash:

```
C:\Users\Nupur>docker run -p 8080:8080 -v C:\\aerospike-kafka-outbound\\aerospike-kafka-outbound.yml:/etc/aerospike-kafka-outbound/aerospike-kafka-outbound.yml aerospike/aerospike-kafka-outbound:4.0.0
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/aerospike-kafka-outbound/aerospike-kafka-outbound.yml" to rootfs at "/etc/aerospike-kafka-outbound/aerospike-kafka-outbound.yml" caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
```

This is my docker directory:

```
C:\Users\Nupur>docker exec -it 1114b8a97406 bash
root@1114b8a97406:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@1114b8a97406:/# cd /etc
root@1114b8a97406:/etc# ls
adduser.conf              ca-certificates.conf  environment  host.conf  ld.so.cache    machine-id     pam.conf   rc1.d  resolv.conf  shells    timezone
aerospike-kafka-outbound  cron.daily            fstab        hostname   ld.so.conf     mke2fs.conf    pam.d      rc2.d  rmt          skel      update-motd.d
alternatives              debconf.conf          gai.conf     hosts      ld.so.conf.d   motd           passwd     rc3.d  securetty    ssl       xattr.conf
apt                       debian_version        group        init.d     libaudit.conf  mtab           passwd-    rc4.d  security     subgid
bash.bashrc               default               group-       issue      localtime      nsswitch.conf  profile    rc5.d  selinux      subuid
bindresvport.blacklist    deluser.conf          gshadow      issue.net  login.defs     opt            profile.d  rc6.d  shadow       systemd
ca-certificates           dpkg                  gshadow-     kernel     logrotate.d    os-release     rc0.d      rcS.d  shadow-      terminfo
root@1114b8a97406:/etc# cd aerospike-kafka-outbound
root@1114b8a97406:/etc/aerospike-kafka-outbound# ls
aerospike-kafka-outbound.yml
root@1114b8a97406:/etc/aerospike-kafka-outbound#
```

Comment: Windows should use double backslash for file paths and you don't need a leading slash

Comment: I added in the question, on using bacsklash.

Comment: I don't run Docker from CMD, personally. I suggest you try using WSL2 since the error seems to say it wants a Unix container

Comment: WSL was not working for me as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70044173/aerospike-err-connection-socket-write-error-32-127-0-0-13000-on-ubuntu-wsl
Thanks @OneCricketeer, I tried on ubuntu on vm.

Comment: You should start the server from some script in the `bin` folder, I assume, not `service` or `systemctl` commands